# Filtering unique values with added condition

Tags: excel

I'd like to get a list of unique values from another column but I want to check with another column as well at the same time.

So, I know that I can use the advanced filter to filter all unique values from a column but in combination with that I want to check of this value has a certain value in it's row on another column.

I have a column with numbers (where there might be multiple instances of the same number) and there's a column next to it with a name (there are about three options in a list of about a thousand items). So if column A is the one with the numbers and B is the one with the name I want to check if B has a certain value when selecting the unique numbers.

Is this possible? I don't mind if it's in VBA or a formula. I hoe I described it clear enough.

Comment: 1) you need to find _unique pairs_ of columns A and B? 2) if yes, what output you want? Remove all duplicate pairs or just copy all unique pairs in new sheet/columns?

Comment: Yes, as output I want only the unique values of column A (so leave column B but use it for checking) and copy them to a new worksheet

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, but perhaps in a way not as convenient as you would like since the output is initially into the same sheet. With Advanced filter you can set criteria as well as apply *Unique records only*:

[image: SO22708052 example]

Only one value for `name` has been selected, but more may be added. The output I think you require is in the image shown in D2:D3 and this would need to be copy/pasted or referenced if required in a different sheet.